# SSRS make Textbox Dropdown list

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to SSRS and I was wondering if I can make a textbox populated with a drop down list based on values that are not present in another textbox
For example: in textbox1 I have the value 1, and I want 2,3,4 to show up in textbox2 as dropdown list.
Is there such away to do that in SSRS?

Comment: By **Textbox**, do you mean **Parameter**? You can't have a drop down in a report. You may want to check out **Cascading Parameters** - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Please explain more what you want this for - do you want both textboxes to be dropdowns, and one cause the other to get its results from a query, or should the first textbox get its results from a query, and offer a dropdown the selection in which will in turn affect the report elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I want textbox2 to be dropdown list that has all the items that has not been showing in textbox1. Textbox1 one is being populated based on the user input in the parameter.  So it he user choose 2 the value in textbox1 should be 2 and the dropdown list (which I am calling it textbox2 here) show 1,3,4 only without 2